# Android: Read dialed numbers during a call

Tags: android

During a call between two persons, if one of the callers dials a number (3 for example), can the other guy receive this number? In other words, can we, as developers, read the dialed numbers from one person to another during a conversation call.
If so, would someone provide a small piece of code?

Answer (score 0):

I think you should look into call DTMF system. I know you can send DTMF signals while in a call. So at the other end just read/decode the DTMF.

Comment: What is the method that allows me to read the DTMF code? For example, if the caller writes 313-423-4567 during a call, do we have a code to read these numbers from the other end?